# Troubles with pacman and wi-fi connection

Tags: arch-linux, wifi, manjaro, pacman

I have troubles with fresh-installed manjaro and pacman.  For example: I'm trying to execute `pacman -Sy` and have such output:

```
error: failed retrieving file 'core.db' from mirrors.colocall.net : Resolving timed out after 10000 milliseconds
```

My wi-fi works fine, I can visit different sites with Firefox.

Help please!

pacman works fine while using wired connection (i used my phone as USB-modem).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your XferCommand to `wget` or `curl` in `/etc/pacman.conf`

Comment: Changed xfer command to wget. Helped. THX!